# Grafana / Azure Monitor - Multidimensional filtering

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-monitoring

I'm using Grafana to monitor Azure Cloud ressources.

I have a problem on Azure cosmos db monitoring :

I want to have multiple dimension filters, and i am not able to do this with grafana but it's possible with azure monitor :

On grafana :

[image]

On Azure Monitor :

[image]

Is there a way to do this via json template or other ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Available since Grafana 7.1 :

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/releases